# How do I change the value of textarea by option selected?

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

I am trying to change the contents of  depending on the current option selected.

The getData(page) comes back correctly (onChange) but it just doesn't go over to the variable I get "Fatal error: Call to undefined function getData() in C:\xampp\htdocs\pdimi\admin\editpages.php on line 42"

EDIT: This is how I finished it!

Javascript:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
function getData(combobox){
var value = combobox.options[combobox.selectedIndex].value;
// TODO: check whether the textarea content has been modified.
// if so, warn the user that continuing will lose those changes and
// reload a new page, and abort function if so instructed.
document.location.href = '?page='+value;
}
</script>
```

Select form:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="page" onChange="getData(this)">
    <?php
if (isset($_REQUEST['page']))
    $page = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['page']);
else
    $page = '';
$query = "SELECT pageid FROM pages;";
?>
<option value="select">Select Page</option>
    <option value="indexpage">Index Page</option>
    <option value="starthere">Start Here</option>

    </select>
```

Textarea:

```
<textarea class="ckeditor" name="page_data" cols="80" row="8" id="page_data">
    <?php
if (isset($_GET['page'])) {
$sql1 = @mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pages WHERE pageid='".$_GET['page']."'") or die(mysql_error());
$sql2 = @mysql_fetch_array($sql1) or die(mysql_error());

if ($sql1) {
echo $sql2['content'];
}
}

?>
</textarea>
```

And that is that!

Comment: I suggest adding some code to this question; HTML, JavaScript.

Comment: Yeah sorry it never added everything. Fixed.

Comment: That looks an awful lot like a PHP error - are you trying to call a Javascript function from your PHP code?

Comment: `$thisdata = ("SELECT * FROM pages WHERE pageid=".getData()` you can't call a javascript function as a php function.

Comment: I am trying to retreive the option value when the person changes from "Index Page" to "Start Here" then take that value and use it in the mysql function. because that way it selects * from indexpage, or starthere in the $thisdata function.

Comment: Yeah I know, but I am trying to get the value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot execute a Javascript function (client side) from PHP (which runs server side).

Also, you need to connect to a database server with user and password, and select a database. Do not use @, it will only prevent you from seeing errors -- but the errors will be there.

In the PHP file you need to check whether you receive a `$_POST['page']`, and if so, use *that* as the ID for the `SELECT`. You have set up a combo named 'page', so on submit the PHP script will receive the selected value into a variable called `$_POST['page']`.

Usual warnings apply:

- mysql_* functions are discouraged, use mysqli or PDO
- if you still use mysql_*, sanitize the input (e.g. `$id = (int)$_POST['page']` if it is numeric, or `mysql_real_escape_string` if it is not, as in your case)

If you want to *change the content of textarea* when the user changes the combo box, that is a work for AJAX (e.g. jQuery):

1. bind a function to the change event of the combo box
2. issue a call to a PHP script server side passing the new ID
3. the PHP script will output *only the content, no other HTML*
4. receive the content in the change-function of the combo and verify success
5. set `$('#textarea')`'s value to the content

This way you won't have to reload the page at each combo change. Which reminds me of another thing, when you *reload the page* now, you have to properly set the combo value: and you can exploit this to dynamically generate the combo, also.

### Working example

This file expects to be called 'editpages.php'. PHP elaboration is done (almost) separately from data presentation.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta name="keywords" content="" />
<meta name="description" content="" />
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>PDIMI - The Personal Development and Internet Marketing Institution</title>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:400,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Abel' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
<link href="../style/default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
<!--[if IE 6]>
<link href="default_ie6.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<![endif]-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
        function getData(combobox){
                var value = combobox.options[combobox.selectedIndex].value;
                // TODO: check whether the textarea content has been modified.
                // if so, warn the user that continuing will lose those changes and
                // reload a new page, and abort function if so instructed.
                document.location.href = '?page='+value;
        }
</script>
</head>
<?php include 'aheader.php';?>
<?php
        error_reporting(E_ALL);
        if (!mysql_ping())
                die ("The MySQL connection is not active.");
        mysql_set_charset('utf8');

        // $_REQUEST is both _GET and _POST
        if (isset($_REQUEST['page']))
            $page = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['page']);
        else
            $page = False;
        $query = "SELECT pageid, pagename FROM pages;";
        $exec  = mysql_query($query); // You need to be already connected to a DB
        if (!$exec)
                trigger_error("Cannot fetch data from pages table: " . mysql_error(), E_USER_ERROR);

        if (0 == mysql_num_rows($exec))
                trigger_error("There are no pages in the 'pages' table. Cannot continue: it would not work. Insert some pageids and retry.",
 E_USER_ERROR);

        $options = '';
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($exec))
        {
            // if the current pageid matches the one requested, we set SELECTED
            if ($row['pageid'] === $page)
                $sel = 'selected="selected"';
            else
            {
                // If there is no selection, we use the first combo value as default
                if (False === $page)
                    $page = $row['pageid'];
                $sel = '';
            }
            $options .= "<option value=\"{$row['pageid']}\" $sel>{$row['pagename']}</option>";
        }
        mysql_free_result($exec);

        if (isset($_POST['page_data']))
        {
           $page_data = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['page_data']);
$query = "INSERT INTO pages ( pageid, content ) VALUES ( '{$page}', '{$page_data}' ) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE content=VALUES(content);";
           if (!mysql_query($query))
                trigger_error("An error occurred: " . mysql_error(), E_USER_ERROR);
        }
        // Anyway, recover its contents (maybe updated)
        $query = "SELECT content FROM pages WHERE pageid='{$page}';";
        $exec  = mysql_query($query);
        // who says we found anything? Maybe this id does not even exist.
        if (mysql_num_rows($exec) > 0)
        {
           // if it does, we're inside a textarea and we directly output the text
           $row = mysql_fetch_array($exec);
           $textarea = $row['content'];
        }
        else
           $textarea = '';
        mysql_free_result($exec);
?>
<body>
<div id="page-wrapper">
        <div id="page">
            <div id="content2">
                    <h2>Edit Your Pages Here</h2>
                    <script type="text/javascript" src="../ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
                    <form name="editpage" method="POST" action="">
                            <table border="1" width="100%">
                                    <tr>
                                    <td>Please Select The Page You Wish To Edit:</td>
                                    <td>
                                            <select name="page" onChange="getData(this)"><?php print $options; ?></select>
                                    </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                            <td><textarea class="ckeditor" name="page_data" cols="80" row="8" id="page_data"><?php print $textarea; ?></textarea></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><input type="Submit" value="Save the page"/></td>
                                    </tr>
                            </table>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
       </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Doesn't answer the question, and I'll look at PDO at some point, but for now I want my basis made.

Comment: you get my vote sir, I don't even know where to begin with this.

Comment: I am trying to get the value of what option is selected, into a variable, then I'll fix it up.

Comment: Sorry, posted the answer half-assed. There were several issues and I saved prematurely; now it ought to be a bit more complete.

Comment: Alright thanks, yeah same thing happened to me. Taking a look now.

Comment: Take care, there's no database connection code anywhere there -- do you have a working MySQL server set up?

Comment: Yeah I have it setup, how do I add jQuery to this? Also what do I need to do for a function? I know mostly php, mysql, html, not much about javascript or jQuery

Comment: I have added a proposal for a Javascript-based modification.

Comment: Looks good but it's not printing any information out, and I edited what I needed.. wierd..

Comment: There was probably an error in the javascript code. You ought to get your hands on a Javascript tutorial on how to exploit the browser's logging/debugging facilities.

Comment: Just from scratch, this gets the value I need: onChange="alert(this.value);" now if only I could get that to save as a variable so I could do something like "SELECT content FROM pages WHERE pageid=".$alertvale

Comment: The code to do so was in the answer, where it manipulates `location.href`. That code sends the value back to PHP. Then in the code below you find how to retrieve that code and use it in a query.

Comment: And how would I debug the javascript because the textarea isn't getting filled with any information.

Comment: I have reworked the page, then copied it from my answer to my server -- in my 'aheader.php', I put the code to connect to the database. It is working; when it does not, it ought to tell you why.

Comment: ALright thanks very much I got it working to and updated my post, I'll check yours too.

Comment: A page is identified by two parameters - the pageid ("starthere") and the pagename displayed in the combo box ("Start Here"). You can do everything with just the pageid, but it's awkward; and using pagename as ID would mean urlencoding (Start Here becomes Start%20Here, etc.). It's much better to keep two columns.

Comment: pagename is undefined, and all of my options are gone, but if I add ?page=starthere then the information does display correctly. Edit: I think I know what you mean now.

Comment: One last question, how do I make Index Page load first by default? It's selected, and in order to edit it, you need to select starthere, and then indexpage.

Comment: You need do nothing. To edit the selected page, just edit the textarea, and click *Save* :-)

Comment: Yes but by default when I go to editpages.php it has indexpage selected, but no data until I add the ?page=indexpage

Comment: Ah, I see. Yes, you need a 'default' select -- you could add a '<option>-- select page --</option>' immediately after <select>, but that would also require checking out the javascript... I'll modify the code in a different way.

Answer (score 0):

The biggest issue that you have here, is that you need to learn the difference between client side and server side.

Server Side: As the page is loading... We run various code to determine what is going to be displayed and printed into the source code.

Client side: Once the page has loaded... We can then use DOM elements to interact, modify, or enhance the user experience (im making this up as i go along).

In your code, you have a PHP mysql command:

```
$thisdata = @mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pages WHERE pageid=".getData('value'));
```

1, Don't use mysql. Use mysqli or PDO
2, You have called a javascript function from your PHP.

There is absolutely no way that you can call a javascript function from PHP. The client side script does not exist and will not run until after the page has stopped loading.

---

In your case:
You need to server up the HTML and javascript code that you will be using. Once, and only when, the page has loaded, you need to use javascript (client side scripting), to set an event listener to listen for your select change event. Once this event is triggered, then you can determine what you want to do (ie change a textbox value, etc).

Comment: I don't want to call a function, that was a mistake, I was trying to get the value of the current option selected